# Object doesn't support property or method 'loadFull'

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer

I'm seeing this error in IE11.

It appears to be related to the angular code in the digest cycle. The stack trace goes down to the ng-view

```
<div class="ng-scope" id="ng-view" ng-view="ng-view" ng-class="{'navbar-hidden': Session.vars.shouldHideNav}" ng-click="Session.hideNavs()">
```

TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'loadFull'

```
TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'loadFull'
   at Anonymous function (eval code:17:438)
   at t (eval code:17:95)
   at Anonymous function (eval code:17:168)
   at eval code (eval code:17:2)
   at a.execScript (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js:2:2615)
   at globalEval (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js:2:2589)
   at domManip (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js:3:23105)
   at append (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js:3:20608)
   at Anonymous function (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js:3:22138)
   at m.access (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js:3:3345) <div class="ng-scope" id="ng-view" ng-view="ng-view" ng-class="{'navbar-hidden': Session.vars.shouldHideNav}" ng-click="Session.hideNavs()">
```

I'm not sure what the cause is and I can't find exactly what the `loadFull` property or method is trying to do or where it is coming from.

angular version: 1.3.15

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up tracking down this bug and finding it was related to a template not being able to load from the server. The request for the template from angular to the server didn't have the right route and seemed as if it wasn't respecting the `<base>` tag in head.

This fixed it.

before:

```
<head>
  <title>Page title</title>
  <!-- A bunch of styles and meta tags --> 
  <base href="/">
</head>
```

after:

```
<head>
  <title>Page title</title>
  <base href="/">
  <!-- A bunch of styles and meta tags --> 
</head>
```

This fixed it.